# Kademlia implementation in c++

Tags: kademlia

I am looking for full kademlia DHT Implementation in c++? I have tried bitdht which is not ver well documented and it is not even fully implemented. Also maidsafe-dht is too complex. Can any one refer to any other implementations except for the ones mentioned above?

Comment: SO is not the right place for this type of questions...

Comment: Where I can ask this question then ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about libtorrent? It is an open source lib in C++.
http://www.libtorrent.org/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.